# tooltip and other formatting on GridViewColumnHeader after column resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I would like to add a tooltip on a `GridViewColumnHeader`, but only if there is not enough space to display all the header's text (after a resize, etc.).

Also, the header text "header's text" should be like "heade..." if there is not enough space.

Is it possible to do that in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm curios why do you have a restriction "only" for showing tooltip.

Second, I guess (didn't try) it is possible with DataTrigger and simple converter.

You can set column header style and define trigger which sets Tooltip when ActualWidth is less than DesiredSize.Width.
This comparison should be performed by converter having DataGridColumnHeader object as an input value.